# IIS connect to SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, api, iis, local

I created an API in ASP.NET and I want to make it reachable by my private IP address.

I created an IIS website and published the API. When I go to my private IP address, I can reach the API. So far so good.(y) But when I ask for data from the API, I get an error: "can't find the SQL Server".

This is my connection string:

```
<add name="AddressBook" 
     connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-96AGTP1;Initial Catalog=AddressBook;Integrated Security=False;User ID=*******;Password=********;
                       Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When I try to debug in Visual Studio I'm able to ask for data. The error only appears when it is published to IIS.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Whats the exact error you got?

Comment: It is in dutch but translated it is: {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Networkerror or copy-specific error while connecting to SQL Server. The Server has not been found or is not accessable. Check the if the servername is correct...}

Comment: Can you see the same connection string in IIS also?

Comment: @SankarRaj in IIS i added the connection string aswell.

Server=DESKTOP-96AGTP1;Database=AddressBook;User ID=vincentvodb;Password=●●●●●●

Comment: can you able to connect now?

Comment: Also check the event log.

Comment: No I'm not able to logging. Where can I find these logs?

Comment: Make sure you have TCP/IP set up as enable in your SQL Server configuration tool.

Comment: TCP/IP was enabled. I changed my Server to the IP and Port, but it is still not working.

Comment: I think you should give exact password rather than `Password=●●●●●●` in IIS.

Comment: I did but I just don't want to put my password on stackoverflow :D